# Where to submit a pedegogic physics paper

Tags: teaching, physics

My co-author and I have a pedagogic paper about a fairly advanced physics topic (we contrast relativistic and non relativistic models of atoms).

The paper doesn't contain any new research per se, but is a novel and clarifying expression of existing material.

Where can we submit such a paper?

Comment: "A novel and clarifying expression of existing material" *is* new research. Read some Education journals. Lots of people propose new, quicker, faster, and/or less expensive ways to teach people how to read. Some of them even work.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen such papers in American Journal of Physics. I would try there. Could also think about Physics Teacher.

Comment: American Journal of Physics has some great pedagogical papers, many of them useful to researchers.